# .htaccess in subfolder for removing extension is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below code is for root folder which are specific to few pages to remove extension. And its working.

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^About+$ about.php
    RewriteRule ^FAQ+$ faq.php
    RewriteRule ^Contact+$ contact.php
    RewriteRule ^Gallery+$ gallery.php
    RewriteRule ^Areas-we-service+$ cities.php


    RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ servicesparse.php?name=$1
```

And then I've added one php plugin is subfolder called product.
    path is root-folder/php-product-catalog-module. Plugin have one another htaccess file in it.

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php-product-catalog-module/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# used for viewing single product page
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\/?$ product.php?name=$1&id=$2

# used for php pages such as "yoursite.com/login.php" will become "yoursite.com/login/"
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
```

So htaccess for subfolder is not working. 
it does not redirect http://cp2.designnrank.com/~wolverin/php-product-catalog-module/login.php to http://cp2.designnrank.com/~wolverin/php-product-catalog-module/login

Rules for other pages of product is not working too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure htaccess is enabled? htaccess files are disabled by default in Apache these days, due to performance issues. When .htaccess files are enabled, the web server must check for it on every hit in every subdirectory from where it resides.

Enabling htaccess can be done by replacing "AllowOverride None" with "AllowOverride All" in the `<Directory></Directory>` directives.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

A better approach is to put all your rewrite rules into a virtualhost configuration file. Something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite-access.log combined

    #Fix Rewrite
    Options -Multiviews

    # Mod Rewrite
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /php-product-catalog-module/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # used for viewing single product page
    RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\/?$ product.php?name=$1&id=$2

    # used for php pages such as "yoursite.com/login.php" will become "yoursite.com/login/"
    RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]

</VirtualHost>
```